# How to run `--shell-escape` for LuaLaTeX in Texshop

Tags: luatex, mac, editors, texshop, shell-escape

Is there a way to run the `--shell-escape` command for the LuaLaTex engine in Texshop? I know there are editable `TEX` and `Latex` commands in the Texshop settings under Engine->pdfTeX settings, but I do not see anything for the LuaLaTeX engine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you always use `lualatex` as your default engine, you can simply replace the LaTeX engine default line in the preferences to read

```
lualatex --file-line-error --synctex=1 --shell-escape
```

I wouldn't really recommend this route, since it's probably best to only use `--shell-escape` when you absolutely need it, rather than make it the default.

I just have an Engine file to do this, or use the `arara` engine. Save the following file as `lualatex-shell.engine` in `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines`.

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set path= ($path /usr/texbin /usr/local/bin)
lualatex --shell-escape --file-line-error --synctex=1 "$1"
```

In the Terminal type:

```
chmod +x ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/lualatex-shell.engine
```

Then restart TeXShop and you can invoke it either by choosing it from the Program item in the Macros menu, or by adding a magic comment line:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex-shell
```

Alternatively, you can use the `arara` engine, and add shell-escape as one of the options.  You may need to move the `arara` engine from the Inactive folder to the main Engines folder (and restart TeXShop) if it doesn't appear in your list of Engines.

```
% !TEX TS-program = arara
% arara: lualatex: {shell: true}
```

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem. I have done all your steps of the first solution. but still get an error: Module lyluatex Error: LilyPond could not be started.
(lyluatex)             Please check that LuaLaTeX is started with the
(lyluatex)             --shell-escape option, and that 'program'
(lyluatex)             points to a valid LilyPond executable.
(lyluatex)             on input line 10

Comment: stack traceback:
 [C]: in function 'error'
 ...ocal/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:110: in function <
...ocal/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109>
 (...tail calls...)
 ./lyluatex.lua:1106: in method 'process'
 [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
\ly@compilescore ...directlua {ly.score:process()}
                                                  
l.10 \end{lilypond}

Comment: The lilypond command works in frescobaldi, so it is not a problem with that code. Pls note I am not a TeX expert, so please keep it simple if you can help !

Comment: @Oбжорoв Since you're trying to combine using lualatex with lilypond, I would recommend asking a new question, linking to this one. I don't think this is something that can be solved in the comments.