# Incorporating Lilypond files in (La)TeX

Tags: lilypond

I am trying to incorporate Lilypond files into LaTeX. I use MacOS Sonoma 14.1.1. TexShop (5.2.2) and write my Lilypond files in Frescobaldi 3.3.0, where they compile into pdf files without a problem.

This question has been asked before, I am incorporating the answer of [How to run `--shell-escape` for LuaLaTeX in Texshop](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/695050/), in particular the steps:

I just have an Engine file to do this, or use the `arara` engine. Save the following file as `lualatex-shell.engine` in `~/Library/TeXShop/Engines`.

```
#!/bin/tcsh

set path= ($path /usr/texbin /usr/local/bin)
lualatex --shell-escape --file-line-error --synctex=1 "$1"
```

In the Terminal type:

```
chmod +x ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/lualatex-shell.engine
```

Then restart TeXShop and you can invoke it either by choosing it from the Program item in the Macros menu, or by adding a magic comment line:

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex-shell
```

I follow all these steps diligently and apply this to several lilypond examples, e.g. my file test4.tex

```
!TEX TS-program = lualatex-shell
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lyluatex}
\begin{document}
\begin{lilypond}
\relative{\time 8/4       \key g \major   g'4 a b c d e fis g}
\end{lilypond}
\end{document}
```

But when I Typeset it in TeXshop or use the terminal I get the following error

> (lyluatex)    Compiling score tmp-ly/e0245313228d92c30cf69cc0a8ddc120 with LilyPond executable 'lilypond'.
> ...ocal/t
> exlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:110:
> Module lyluatex Error: LilyPond could not be started.
> (lyluatex)             Please check that LuaLaTeX is started with the
> (lyluatex)             --shell-escape option, and that 'program'
> (lyluatex)             points to a valid LilyPond executable.
> (lyluatex)             on input line 9
>
> stack traceback:
> [C]: in function 'error'
> ...ocal/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:110: in function <
> ...ocal/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ltluatex.lua:109>
> (...tail calls...)
> ./lyluatex.lua:1106: in method 'process'
> [\directlua]:1: in main chunk.
> \ly@compilescore ...directlua {ly.score:process()}
>
> l.9 \end{lilypond}

I am complete at a loss here as it seems to know the lyluatex package but find an error in a lilypond code.

Can anyone help me resolve this.

Please note that I am not a (La)TeX expert keep it simple if you can !

Comment: In your MWE, the line `\begin{lilypond}` is missing. It looks like the `lyluatex` package can't find Lilypond. Did you check the [`lyluatex` manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/support/lyluatex/lyluatex.pdf)?

Comment: The manual says: "By default lyLuaTEX invokes LilyPond simply as `lilypond`." If you type this command in the command line (Terminal on macOS), does Lilypond start up? If not, you might need to tell `lyluatex` where it should look for LilyPond using the `program` option.

Comment: @JasperHabicht that's a typo in my question! now corrected.

Comment: @JasperHabicht When I type "lilypond" or "lilypond test4" or "lyluatex" in terminal. It says command not found. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So there are two issues here. The first is how your `lilypond` is installed. I have it installed using `homebrew`, and so the location of my `lilypond` executable is in `/opt/homebrew/bin`.  If you didn't install it that way, then your executable maybe somewhere else, and you need to be able to tell your Engine file where to find it.  If you install `lilypond` with `homebrew` you simply need to add `/opt/homebrew/bin` to the path in the Engine file:

```
set path= ($path /usr/texbin /usr/local/bin /opt/homebrew/bin)
lualatex --shell-escape --file-line-error --synctex=1 "$1"
```

And then you can use this Engine to compile your file. But until you have a way to run `lilypond` from the command line it won't work.  Once you do get it running, then you need to replace the `/opt/homebrew/bin` path with whatever is the actual path of your `lilypond` executable.

If you installed `lilypond` by simply unzipping the `.zip` file from the `lilypond.org` download page, then you have a folder `lilypond-2.24.3` (the actual version number might be different) somewhere in your machine.  Assuming you put this into your Applications folder, then the path to `lilypond` you would put into the Engine would be:

```
/Applications/lilypond-2.24.3/bin
```

This will not let you run `lilypond` from the command line without further adding this path to your shell `.profile` (or equivalent). For this reason, I would recommend installing `lilypond` with `homebrew`, since it will correctly set the path for any `homebrew` installed software.

Comment: I don't understand. I have a lilypond.exe file in a ~/Documents/Music/_Lilypond/bin directory, but even if I try to run it from there in the terminal I get a "command not found". But if I click on lilypond.exe in Finder it starts a process and ends it with no apparent error.  ??

Comment: @Oбжорoв Well there's your problem right there. If the file is really called `lilypond.exe` then it's a Windows executable and won't run on your Mac at all. I would recommend first installing Homebrew from [here](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/releases/tag/4.1.21) and then using `brew install lilypond` from the terminal to install `lilypond`. Then the instructions I give at the beginning of this answer should work.  Lilypond is not a program that is designed to be run from the Finder.

Comment: fyi. I have once more downloaded lilypond.org and moved the lilypond-2.24.3 folder to my applications. I have added the address /Applications/lilypond-2.24.3/bin to the lualatex-shell.engine file and entered chmod +x ~/Library/TeXShop/Engines/lualatex-shell.engine in the terminal. I have exit TexShop (and Mac even) and restarted it . Still the same error.

Comment: @Oбжорoв Another reason to use `homebrew` to install. When you install `lilypond` the way you did, the MacOS will issue an error saying that it comes from an unknown developer, and will not let you run it. To overcome this, you need to navigate to the `/Applications/lilypond-2.24.3/bin` folder, select the `lilypond` command, and control click and choose "Open". This will then ask you if you trust the developer. Choose yes, and things should work. But I suspect the other executables within that folder will also pose problems, so I reiterate my suggestion to use Homebrew to install `lilypond`.

Comment: I am not sure, but with all your help I managed to make it work from the terminal (using lualatex --escape-shell test4.tex). Doesn't work from the TeXShop (yet) but I can certainly live with this. Thanks ever soooo much!!!

Comment: @Oбжорoв I'm glad you've got something working. But I've tested both paths with this Engine on my machine it they both work. Do you still get the same error with TeXShop?

Comment: yes. Still the same error with TeXshop. But I am fine with the solution I have. And it feels good to be using commands as in the good old days! If you post it as a short answer, I will be happy to accept the answer.

Comment: @Oбжорoв I think I'll just leave the answer as is. As I said, I think the best solution to this problem is to make sure `lilypond` is installed with Homebrew, and the answer as it stands should work for others. It's not entirely clear why it's still not working in your particular setup.