Minted package does not work with TeXShop
I'm using TeXShop on Mac and I cannot use minted package even after following the official documentation.
In TeXShop settings, in engine, I've added -shell-escape at the end of the string in Tex and Latex (pdfTeX window), but when I compile the file using LuaLaTeX there is always the You must invoke LaTeX with the -shell-escape flag. error.
Any suggestion?
Pygments installed (version 2.18), TeXShop updated to latest version.

I cannot really help, because I'm not using TeXShop. But maybe it would be useful for others to add a description (or even an image) to show where exactly you've changed which setting to exactly what new setting. Similar to the question here.

Can you show the first couple of lines of the .log file?

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz here you are:
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023)
restricted system commands enabled.
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class

@Katherine Thanks! restricted system commands enabled means that the document is not complied with shell-escape.

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/695051/36296 has some suggestions how to use shell-escape with lualatex in texshop

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz creating my own engine I have this error in the log:
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.16.0 (TeX Live 2023)
system commands enabled.
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>

@Katherine Looks good, system commands are now enabled.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz yes, the problem was that pygmentize was not found, but now it works. thanks a lot!

@Katherine Great to hear you got it working now!
